# Configuring IIS Authentication from Ansible

Tags: windows, iis, ansible, winrm

I have an Ansible solution communicating from a Linux Control machine to a Windows Dev server. I able to start/stop IIS from Ansible task using below:

```
- name: Restart IIS site
  when: sitename == 'yes'
  win_iis_website:
   name: "sitename"
   state: restarted
   port: 8080
  register: website
```

Above works perfectly fine, now I want to enable/disable IIS Authentication for this published site for example, but could not find a direct way to achieve this:

1. Forms Authentication="Enabled"
2. Windows Authentication="Disabled"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`win_dsc` Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_dsc.html), [`xWebAdministration` Powershell DSC module and `xWebsite` resource](https://github.com/dsccommunity/xWebAdministration) to configure IIS Authentication.

```
- name: Install xWebAdministration Powershell module
  win_psmodule:
    name: xWebAdministration
    state: present

- name: Create new IIS website and configure authentication
  win_dsc:
    resource_name: xWebsite
    Name: NewIISSite
    State: Started
    PhysicalPath: C:\inetpub\IISSite\index.html
    BindingInfo:
    - Protocol: http
      Port: 8080
      IPAddress: '*'
    AuthenticationInfo:
      Anonymous: no
      Basic: yes
      Digest: no
      Windows: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by including/updating the web.config while deploying your solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  ....
  </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```